# Karate BDD URL encoding issue

Tags: rest, karate

I am trying to automate the endpoint [BestBuy](http://localhost:3030/products?$select[]=name&$select[]=price) which has special characters and the resource URI is **/products?$select[]=name&$select[]=price**

I have also added the configuration for the UTF-8 encoding in the maven-surefire-plugin as below under the /build/plugins

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But when am running (either through IDE or mvn test on the terminal) am getting error as 404 not found, and in the error getting

> info: (404) Route: /products%3F$select%5B%5D=name&$select%5B%5D=pbrice
>   - Page not found

Appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix by altering the test as below.

```
    Given path 'products'
    And param $select[] = 'name'
    And param $select[] = 'price'
    When method get
    Then status 200
    Then print response
```

Posting, so that can be helpful for someone who might be facing similar issue.

Reference URL: [Karate Test](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/greeting/greeting.feature)

Comment: It says I can mark my own answer only after 2 days, will wait for 2 days and then mark as answer.